# how to attach existing value to an input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a html form and in one of the inputs, i need to attach a word(like ,1 or ,2) to what user had entered. what should i do?

in this form we have a plus button that user can add more input like this one down. so i generate an id for them but i really don't know why i did that.

```
  <input name='singleOption[0]' class='form-control single' type='text' id='singleOption_0' />
  <input name='singleOption[1]' class='form-control single' type='text' id='singleOption_1' />
  <input name='singleOption[2]' class='form-control single' type='text' id='singleOption_2' />


 <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='addInput()'>add input</button>

 <script>
       addInput(){
           // i append them to the div
           $(".t-content").find("input.single").each(function(i) {
                 $(this).attr("id", "singleOption_" + i).attr("name", "singleOption[" + i + "]");
           });
       }
 </script>
```

i expected when the user entered fruit to my input i recieve 'fruit,1' in controller

Comment: what fruit come from input?

Comment: it was example. like user entered a word. like fruit and i want to recieve fruit,1 in backend

Comment: where do you want to store fruit, 1

Comment: in my database. string type

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you just want to send the input text to backend use jquery ajax.
If you want something else then please explain your question.Thanks

```js
function send()
{
var mydata=$("#MyText").val();
$.ajax
({
type:"post",
url:"@Url.Action("ActionMethodName","ControllerName")",
data:{Name:mydata},
success:function()
{
alert("success");
}
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="MyText" placeholder="Enter Something here" name="Name"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="send()"value="Submit"/>
```